# How to find the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, continuity

For $x \in [0, \pi/2]$, if

$$f_n(x) = \frac {nx} {1+n\sin(x)}$$

how do you find the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$ ?

Comment: Divide the numerator and the denominator by $n$, and see what happens as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: if it's point-wise you can just use l'hopital's rule (differentiating with respect to $n$)

Comment: As per the comments pointwise limit must be - $\frac {x} {1+sin(x)} $ ?

Comment: Is that true here ?

Comment: @Kittu If you're attacking it with L'Hospital, the differentiation removes the $1$. Otherwise you're fine (except where $\sin(x)=0$, where the use of L'Hospital was not justified).

Comment: @lan okay, Is it defined for $x \in [0, \pi/2]$  ?

Comment: @Kittu where did you get this problem from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the sine function obeys the bound $0\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Taking the limit of $f_n$ as $n\to\infty$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{1+n\sin(x)}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & \text{for}~x=0, \\ 
\frac{x}{\sin(x)}, & \text{for}~0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}. 
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}
To get the limit for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, use either L'Hopital's rule or divide the numerator and denominator of $f_n(x)$ by $n$.